# What's the purpose of firelayers.net?

Tags: google-chrome

I was browsing information regarding a Google Play Music feature and found a post on the Google Product forums. I went onto it, however I realised the URL was different.

```
https://productforums-google-com.firelayers.net
```

The official address is https://productforums.google.com. However, the firelayers page seemed identical to the actual page. I thought it may have been a phishing page but it has a https certificate and according to a whois search, it seems to be owned by "proofpoint inc". As well as that, any clicked links on the firelayers version of the site redirect to the normal official version.

I'm just wondering, what is the purpose of these alternative versions of the google product forums and what is the purpose of firelayers, and are those pages safe?

Comment: Seems to be actual companies, but I wouldn't trust something like this. A google search suggests they're some kind of security company so I guess its a misconfigured proxy/MITM setup of some sort. If I saw something like that, my first reaction would be to not trust this.

Comment: Would there have been any risk from just accessing the site briefly? I didn't input anything onto it.

Comment: Probably not. If it was dodgy, it would be a great way to phish for usernames/passwords. Reporting them to google sounds like a *great* idea https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?rd=1&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It is safe.

**What is the *purpose* of Firelayers.net?**

It has to do with a DBaaS (Database as a Service) technology which Google acquired and now uses for many of their own apps called Firebase. Firebase is a really sweet NoSQL, full JSON (Javascript object) document storage system which you may notice comes prebaked into every Google Cloud Developer service.

Firelayers is (was?) a startup which offered an interesting kind of Cloud Application Security Gateway which used Firebase technology (now owned by Google) to manage authentication and data security to many Google Apps, and looking at your network profile while running Google Apps you can see some requests to firelayers.net domain.

There's nothing specific on a cursory glance of the company's history with Google, but if you asked me, Google is or has already acquired Firelayers to fold their authentication into what they already own.

Your concern is valid though, I also get freaked out when a domain randomly changes. I'm guessing that some or all of Google Product Forums is being delivered through Firelayers.

Comment: When I had initially searched Firelayers it showed results that it had been acquired by "Proofpoint" as of October, 2016.  Would you know about what involvement they may have now with it?

Comment: Like I said, not specifically, but Firelayers material and various articles seem to indicate that many enterprise-level cloud services like AWS and [Google Apps use Firelayers in their delivery systems](https://medium.com/@doctusoft/doctusoft-announces-partnership-with-firelayers-to-deliver-cloud-application-security-solutions-to-b68c19b17fb9#.ivhzlm8ve). Still, this domain redirection is probably a bug and not a feature -- it's freaky to be on a page and realize you are now sending requests to "cloud-google-com.firelayers.net", as some of my requests to Google Apps seem to be.